# Android - How to add a background image for first item in a GridView having custom adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I want to add a background image only to the first item ( not the first visible item ) in a grid view which has a custom adapter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok ! you can check the position in your custom adapter method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

that `if position ==1` then set background whatever you want.

Comment: It works, but when using static holder pattern need to take care of resetting the background as we will be using the same view.